# Fetch Employee records from One model to another in ODOO 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

How to create records directly from hr employee model into my new model. In hr model I have some employee records, I have to retrieve those records and store into my new model by code. Please help me.

Comment: put a create method in hr.employee for your new model@Prashanth

Comment: i did not get, please write code.

Comment: try on you own to educate yourself instead of asking blindly, I gave you an idea, USE IT@Prashanth

Comment: i tried from two days.but no solution.please help me.

Comment: Post your python code, i ll do@Prashanth

Comment: @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = super(Employee, self).create(vals) 
        if record.name  and record.birthday:
            self.env['hr.birthday'].create({
                'name': record.name,
                'birthday_date': record.birthday,
                
            })
        return res_id

Comment: Kindly accept my edit@Prashanth K

Comment: class Birthday(models.Model):
    
    _name='hr.birthday'
 

    name=fields.Char(string="Name")
    birthday_date=fields.Date(string="Birthday")        

i have to add name  and birthday fields from hr.employee meodel into hr.birthday model when i create the records in hr.employee

Comment: how to write domain for to intimate before 3 days of current date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49630050/9020824

Comment: <field name="domain">[('today','&gt;=','date_from'),('today','&lt;=','date_to')]</field>

Comment: domain showing error what is the problem navven

Comment: what error?????

Comment: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "date_from" showing this error

Comment: today = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Datetime.now) field syntax

Comment: you can't simply compare two date fields

Comment: what shall i do

Comment: please help me ,I'm new to odoo

Comment: my stack over flow reputation is low to upvote, that is the prblm to upvote your answer

Comment: send your domain view fully

Comment: <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="act_employee_from_today_leaves">
      <field name="name">Today Anniversary</field>
      <field name="res_model">hr.holidays</field>
     <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
     <field name="domain">[('today','&gt;=','date_from'),('today','&lt;=','date_to')]</field>
      <field name="context">{}</field>
      
      <field name="view_mode">kanban</field>
      
     </record>

Comment: [('context_today()','&gt;=','date_from'),('context_today()','&lt;=','date_to')]

Comment: naveen but here date_to and date_from are Datetime fields

Comment: ya i know but you cant compare two date fields

Comment: hi Naveen ,how to add the total records count on top of kanban card

Comment: come on that is very easy, please check on addons modules

Comment: i checked, but i did get anything.

Comment: <span class="dash-box-count"><t t-esc="birthday_count"/></span>

Comment: def birthday_report(self,context=None):

        rec = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('birthday','like',date.today().strftime("%____%-%m-%d"))])
        print rec,'*************'
        data = {}
        data['form'] = rec.read(['name', 'birthday', 'work_email','mobile_phone','age'])
        print data['form'],"*************************"

        return self.env['report'].get_action(rec, 'hr_birthdays.report_contributionregister_birthdays',data=data)

Comment: <tr t-foreach="data" t-as="o">
                <td class="td-lrbotborder">
                    <span t-esc="o['name']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
                </td>
                <td class="td-botborder">
                    <span t-esc="o['birthday']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
                  </td>
                  <td class="td-botborder">
                    <span t-esc="o['age']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
                  </td>
                  
                   
          </tr>

Comment: how to return data['form'] dictionary to the t-foreach loop in reports templates

Comment: above code printing empty report

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49777308/9020824

Comment: domain is not working for non -stored field,when i write store=True that field is not calculate always.Please give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@api.model 
def create(self, vals):
record = super(Employee, self).create(vals) 
if record.name and record.birthday: 

    return self.env['hr.birthday'].create({
                                    'name': record.name,
                                    'birthday_date': record.birthday
                                            }) 
return record
```

Comment: it's working fine, but i need already created records also update into my new model hr.employee , please give me idea ,thanks

Comment: Sorry Prashanth that will be complicated, but it can be achieved when you put this function inside a button. So that all the old records will be created in your new model, or write a cron job method to get the old records@PrashanthK

Comment: ok Naveen, i'm trying to add new kanban view for hr.employee model , i give the different actions for two kanban view , but it's showing same views for two kanban views.How can i add two different kanban view for same model. please help for this.

Comment: Give different names and id

Comment: i gave name and id is different , but the view are override , so it's giving same for two kanban view , the problem is model is same.

Comment: <record id="open_view_employee_list_my" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Employees</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <
            
            <field name="view_id" eval="False"/>
            
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_employee_filter"/>
            
            </field>
        </record>

Comment: <record id="open_view_categ_birthday_kanban" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Today Birthday</field>
            <field name="res_model">hr.employee</field>
            <field name="domain">[('birthday','like',context_today().strftime("%____%-%m-%d"))]</field>
            <field name="context">{}</field>
            
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,form,tree</field>
            
        </record>

Comment: tell me naveen ,what help

Comment: please naveen help me , how to get all records into my new model

Comment: hi naveen, please help me , how to create a button on top of the kanban view

Comment: You didn't still upvoted my questions and answes@PrashanthK

Comment: don't know naveen

Comment: please tell me i want inherit the kanban view to my custom module without any changes, i used _inherit='hr.employee' in py file and <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.hr_kanban_view_employees"/> in xml file, but it showing error, i didn't mention _name in my custom module. please help me.

Comment: please check my question

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/49630050/9020824 please check my query,please help me