# How to send the dictionary data from method to reports foreach loop in odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I wrote method to print the reports,but I'm getting empty data.Please check the below code and help me.

```
def birthday_report(self,context=None):

    rec = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('birthday','like',date.today().strftime("%____%-%m-%d"))])
    print rec,'*************'
    data = {}
    data['form'] = rec.read(['name', 'birthday', 'work_email','mobile_phone','age'])
    print data['form'],"*************************"

    return self.env['report'].get_action(rec, 'hr_birthdays.report_contributionregister_birthdays',data=data)
```

The report code is:

```
<tbody>
        <tr t-foreach="data" t-as="o">
            <td class="td-lrbotborder">
                <span t-esc="o['name']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
            </td>
            <td class="td-botborder">
                <span t-esc="o['birthday']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
              </td>
              <td class="td-botborder">
                <span t-esc="o['age']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
              </td>
              <td class="td-botborder">
                <span t-esc="o['mobile_phone']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
              </td>
             <td class="td-botborder">
                <span t-esc="o['work_email']" style=" font-size:13px;" />
              </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TodayBirthdayReport(models.AbstractModel):
_name = 'report.hr_birthdays.report_birthdays'


@api.model
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    if not data.get('form'):
        raise UserError(_("Form content is missing, this report cannot be printed."))

    register_ids = self.env.context.get('active_ids', [])
    contrib_registers = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(register_ids)
    docs = self.env['hr.employee'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_id'))
    rec = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('birthday','like',date.today().strftime("%____%-%m-%d"))])

    data1 = {}
    data1['form'] = rec.read(['name', 'birthday', 'work_email','mobile_phone','age','image_medium'])


    lines_data = data1['form']

    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': register_ids,
        'doc_model': 'hr.dashboard',
        'docs': contrib_registers,
        'data': data,
        'lines_data': lines_data,

    }
    return self.env['report'].render('hr_birthdays.report_birthdays', docargs)
```